# Filtering python lists using another list

Tags: python-3.x

How to look up if a string in one list is a part of another list:

```
b_names = ['robert', 'jon', 'arya']
a_names = ['rya', 'fish']


def filterA(name):
for string in b_names:
    if name in string:
        return True
    else :
        return False

final_list = filter(filterA,a_names)
```

The final_list is empty and should have contained the string rya since rya is present as a substring in the arya from the first list.

What is the error here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loop is ending too early.

If `name` is not in `string`, it returns `False`. With `Robert` being first item in `b_names`, it ends the loop and does not continue to `Jon` or `Arya`. You need to put your `return False` after your `for` loop

```
b_names = ['robert', 'jon', 'arya']
a_names = ['rya', 'fish']


def filterA(name):
    for string in b_names:
        if name in string:
            return True

    return False


final_list = filter(filterA, a_names)
print final_list

>>> ['rya']
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting I think I somehow have overlooked the filterA logic. Thanks much